# rotate bitmap in ViewPager

Tags: android

Следующий код выводит изображение с камеры требует, но его еще нужно перевернуть. Как это сделать?

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("test", "Вход в метод onCreateView()");
        View swipeView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.swipe_fragment, container, false);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) swipeView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        int position = bundle.getInt("position");
        //imageView.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(mPathFile[position], 990, 742));

        Log.d("test", "Метод onCreateView() position - " + position);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(pathFile.get(position), 990, 742));

        getExifOrientation(pathFile.get(position));

        Log.d("test", "Выход из метода onCreateView()");
        return swipeView;
    }
```

что в этом методе не так?

```
public static String getExifOrientation(String filepath) {
        String degree = "0";
        ExifInterface exif = null;
        try {
            exif = new ExifInterface(filepath);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Log.e("test", "cannot read exif", ex);
        }
        if (exif != null) {
            int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, -1);
            if (orientation != -1) {
                switch (orientation) {
                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                        degree = "180";
                        //exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, "180");
                        break;
                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                        degree = "90";
                        exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, "180");

                        break;
                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                        degree = "270";
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        //exif.saveAttributes();
        rotate(filepath, degree);
        Log.e("test", "degree - " + degree);
        return degree;

    }

    public static void rotate(String filepath, String degrees) {
        try {
            ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(filepath);
            exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, getExifOrientation(filepath));
            exif.saveAttributes();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.w("test", "cannot set exif data: ");
```

}
}

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что вы просто перезаписываете метаданные к файлу, а надо поворачивать именно сам bitmap.
Один из вариантов можете посмотреть тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9015372/how-to-rotate-a-bitmap-90-degrees